# How to give grained IAM control for AWS Aurora?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds

I want to give a least privilege IAM policy to control creation and deletion of AWS Aurora instances. Rights for DB Instances working fine, but DB Cluster objects can not be deleted:

```
User xxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: rds:DeleteDBCluster
```

Here is what rights I want:

```
{
  "Sid": "313",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "rds:ModifyDBCluster",
    "rds:DeleteDBCluster"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:123456789101:cluster:*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "rds:cluster-tag/author": "qa"
    }
  }
}
```

But as far as I tested only this works:

```
{
  "Sid": "313",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "rds:ModifyDBCluster",
    "rds:DeleteDBCluster"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Comment: please forgive me if this is a silly question, but i guess you double checked the aws region, account number and condition are all met?

Comment: yup, i've checked all this. i plan to open support request. will return here with results.

Comment: Yes please do keep us posted if you open a case, this is interesting

Comment: Did you get an update on this?

Comment: Nope. I think it's not possible.